# Python Function error

Tags: python, function

I wrote a simple function program. The program works by itself but when converted to a function, it gives the character count of 1. I am using Python version 3.5.

```
def sink(x,y):
  x = ['a','a','b','c']
  y = 'c'

  count = {}
  for char in x:
    count.setdefault(char,0)
    count[char] = count[char]+1
  print (count.get(y,0))



sink (['a','a','c','d','e','e'],'e')
```

Comment: Not a great use of `setdefault`, you could use `collections.defaultdict(int)` for `count` or alternatively just `count[char] = count.get(char, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are overwriting values of `x`, `y` at the beginning, try

```
def sink(x, y):
    count = {}
    for char in x:
        count.setdefault(char, 0)
        count[char] = count[char] + 1
    print(count.get(y, 0))


sink(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e'], 'e')
```

also we can improve your function by [returning](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) value from it and printing outside and using [augmented arithmetic assignment `+=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/)

```
def sink2(x, y):
    count = {}
    for char in x:
        count.setdefault(char, 0)
        count[char] += 1
    return count.get(y, 0)


print(sink(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e'], 'e'))
```

finally we can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) methods:

```
def sink3(x, y):
    return ''.join(x).count(y)


print(sink3(['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e'], 'e'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a `Counter` object that does this, and `Counter` returns `0` for a value not seen already, so is simply:

```
from collections import Counter
def sink(x, y):
    return Counter(x)[y]

>>> sink(['a','a','c','d','e','e'], 'e')
2
```

Comment: This is true, yes, but wouldn't it be slightly arbitrary? `Counter` is a function in itself.. lol

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. `Counter` is a type, similar to a multiset